# git remote server path error

Tags: git, ssh

I am using a windows server as my git server and my local machine is running on windows too. When I add origin with

> `ssh://Administrator@myserver:/~/test.git`

it works fine. But when I try to add the same path with

> `ssh://Administrator@myserver/c:/Users/Administrator/test.git`

and try to push, it says

> `fatal: '/c:/Users/Administrator/b4 tsj/bla.git' does not appear to be
>   a git repository fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.'

I've tried giving the path in several ways referring answers from similar questions. Neither `Administrator@myserver/c:/Users/...` or `Administrator@myserver:c:/Users/...` or `Administrator@myserver/c/Users/...` works. Same message appears when I try to push. What am I doing wrong here?

I'm new to git and I want to create my remote repo at somewhere other than c: in server. But I'm stuck here right now since I can't specify the path. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Not actually a git issue. The problem here is that ssh doesn't know what a URI with "/c:" in it means. You need to either change which SSH client your git is using, or change your URL to no have a colon in it. Samba paths are good. Or have a look at some of the suggestions on [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme).

Comment: @paul Thanks for replying. But without colon 'Administrator@myserver/c/Users/...' either does not work. And I actually do not understand samba paths. Looked at the wiki page but couldn't find any working path style there either.

Comment: You always need to have a colon after `myserver`, what about `ssh://Administrator@myserver:/c/Users/...`?

Comment: Different ssh clients interpret the URI differently. I can't tell exactly how to remove the colon after the C with only the information in your question. Read the wikipedia page and try a few things. But the best solution is to make it a network URI (http, samba, nfs, or similar) instead of a filesystem one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved by giving the address without `ssh://` part. 
i.e. using just

> `Administrator@myserver/c:/Users/Administrator/test.git`

I have no idea how the problem occurred or solved. However now its fine and thanks for your comments everyone.